# How do I make a closure that avoids a redundant clone of captured variables?

Tags: rust, closures, clone

I'm trying to implement the classic `make_adder` function which takes an addable thing and returns a closure which takes another addable thing and returns the sum. Here is my attempt:

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn make_adder<T: Add + Clone>(x: T) -> impl Fn(T) -> T::Output {
    move |y| x.clone() + y
}
```

Because I don't want to restrict `T` to be `Copy`, I'm calling `clone()` inside the closure. I think this also means there will always be one redundant `x` captured by the closure as the "prototype". Can I somehow do this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realistically, you cannot avoid this. You never know if the closure will be called another time; you will need to keep the value in case it is. I wouldn't worry about performing the clone until profiling has identified that this is a bottleneck.

---

In certain cases, you might be able to change your closure type to `FnOnce`, which enforces that it can only be called exactly once:

```
fn make_adder<T>(x: T) -> impl FnOnce(T) -> T::Output
where
    T: Add,
{
    move |y| x + y
}
```

In other cases, you might be able to add some indirection to the problem. For example, instead of passing a `T`, pass in a closure that generates a `T` (presumably not by cloning its own captured variable...). This `T` can always be consumed directly:

```
fn make_adder<T>(x: impl Fn() -> T) -> impl Fn(T) -> T::Output
where
    T: Add,
{
    move |y| x() + y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use a reference, if you’re using types that support addition on references (probably all the useful ones do, including the built-in numeric types).

```rust
fn make_adder<T, U>(x: T) -> impl Fn(T) -> U
where
    for<'a> &'a T: Add<T, Output = U>,
{
    move |y| &x + y
}
```

or

```rust
fn make_adder<'a, T>(x: &'a T) -> impl Fn(T) -> <&'a T as Add<T>>::Output
where
    &'a T: Add<T>,
{
    move |y| x + y
}
```

Comment: The first one doesn't really solve the problem, AFAICT. The closure is still owning a copy of the value that will never be used by anything but the closure itself.

Comment: @Shepmaster It avoids the `clone()` inside the closure, which was one of the OP’s concerns. I agree that the second one is likely better if you’re willing to have the callers pass a reference.

Comment: I mean, you could "avoid the `clone`" by creating another trait with a different name, but as I see OPs question, the underlying issue is the "wasted" object.